# jQuery getting div text on change problem

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

this is my view

```
<div class="product-sort-section flex-row flex-justify flex-center"><span></span>
          <div class="custom-select">

              <div class="select_cat select-title">Cортировать</div>
                <ul class="dropdown select-list">   
                   @foreach ($categories as $category)
                     <li>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('front.category.ru', $category->slug) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
                     </li> 
                   @endforeach
                </ul>                      

          </div>            
        </div>
```

and i try to get div text when it changes with jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.select_cat').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
         var cat = $(".select_cat").html();
         console.log(cat.trim());
      });

    });
</script>
```

when I try to leave div text to browser log I get two strings one is empty another one is needed category name but with some space. How can I get only div text inside my script? thanks for your answers.

Comment: forgot to mention, <div class="select_cat select-title">Cортировать</div> takes whatever is selected in the <ul> list

Comment: You can change the trigger if something selected or deselected from your list and grab the select_cat text.

Comment: Anyway, how do you put the text in the div.select_cat when something is selected from the list?

Answer (score 0):

Use `text` method instead of `html`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.select_cat').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
         var cat = $(".select_cat").text();
         console.log(cat.trim());
      });

    });
</script>
```

Instead of using `JQuery` `html` method to add text into the div, use plan javascript method `textContent`.

Use plan javascript method instead of `JQuery` `html/text` method.

> JQuery is clearing the div content first and then adding the new text, that's why `DOMSubtreeModified` event is executing twice, one on empty node and the other with the actual content.

Example.

```
function changeContent() {
        let select_cat = document.querySelector('.select_cat');
        select_cat.textContent = 'New Content';
}
```

Comment: it's a Jquery bug or something but Jquery is modifying like that. First it's clearing content of the div and then adding the new content, you could use vanilla javascript for this.